# Eclipse Jetty Integration, how to setup dependencies?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, dependencies, jetty

I use Eclipse Jetty Integration and assume this will manage my java ee dependencies but it doesn't seem to do so? How do I set this up?

I've installed Eclipse Jetty Integration v4.0 from the marketplace. I setup a dynamic web project. Without any java code this works fine. When I create a Jetty WebApp and run it index.html shows nicely.

Then I create a servlet. Which depends on sub packages of javax.servlet

These dependencies cannot be found.

I have tried adding from eclipse libraries to the classpath and been googling all night, but to no avail. I could download a version of jetty and import all the libraries from it to my classpath.

I expect that Eclipse Jetty Integration will happily fix this for me, if only I could find the proper button to press or the right library to include.

If this is not the proper way to set up my dependencies, then what would be the proper way?

Comment: Can you have the project "target" the Java EE Preview server? It doesn't look like it would conflict with how this plugin is launching your app.

Comment: nitind, I wish I could flag your comment as the answer, because it was.

My line of thinking was that I should be able to use the dependencies supplied by the jetty server included in the Eclipse Jetty Integration project. 

Your solution, doesn't include those but, seems to include the default java-ee dependencies. Which also works. And for my purposes right now that is more than good enough. I hope I don't bump into differences between the two api's at a later stage. But I'll cross that bridge when I come to it. 

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

"Eclipse Jetty Integration" is a plugin (not maintained by the Eclipse Jetty project btw) that allows you to run webapps (WAR projects) easily from the Eclipse IDE.

The project has to still be valid, in a standalone sense, with all of its various dependencies (compilation / runtime / provided / test / etc), so that the Eclipse IDE can compile your project.

The Servlet API is compilation / provided dependency that your project needs to compile, but does not need to include in its produced WAR file (usually your dependencies show up in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory in the WAR file).

It's up to you, and your project, to determine where you want your dependencies .. eg: in your WAR, outside your WAR, in the server classpath, the webapp classpath.
Will you be using JNDI?  if so, you'll have to be conscious on how you declare your JNDI resources, and how you intend to access those resource.
Will you be serializing objects to HttpSession?  then you'll need to be aware of where your dependencies are (server / webapp / on a cluster / is the serialized data going to be accessed from multiple webapps), so that the deserialization will work as you want it to.

The most common (and I really mean *THE* most common) way to setup/manage/maintain your dependencies is with a build tool (Maven or Gradle), and let those tools worry about how your project is built, packaged, and tested.

Yes, the Eclipse IDE supports both Maven and Gradle based projects and integrates wonderfully with both.

Note: Running your project from the Eclipse IDE does NOT require the "Eclipse Jetty Integration" plugin.  In fact more developers (in a ratio of nearly 45:1 based on various industry surveys) just use embedded jetty techniques to run the project or to setup unit testing of their project.

Comment: Thank you Joakim, I don't mean my own dependencies, but the dependencies supplied by jetty, generally those that I wouldn't manage because they're included with the server.

Comment: That's still done by your project, in maven terms that would be a dependency in your project marked with `<scope>provided</scope>`.